# Setting backspace in vim

Tags: vim

I am using mac so technically I want to set the <kbd>Delete</kbd> to act as a <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

when I use

```
:fixdel
```

It started acting as a <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, but I want to use it as <kbd>Backspace</kbd> instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your vimrc:

> set backspace=indent,eol,start